# How to stop drag after reaching a specific speed

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, drag, rigid-bodies

I have the following code which adds force to a rigidbody2d in a random direction and attempts to set the linear drag to 0 when a specific speed is reached, essentially letting the gameobject slowly float away.

The problem is that the drag seems to be set to 0 straight away, and I do not understand why, and therefore I am unable to solve the problem

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) {
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        Vector3 dir = Random.onUnitSphere;
        rb.AddForce (dir * 10, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    if (rb.velocity.magnitude <= 1) {
        rb.drag = 0;
    }
}
```

Thank you
Crouz

Comment: You're setting velocity to 0 when hitting space, which sets the magnitude to 0. The force you're applying is probably not setting the velocity.magnitude to `<= 1` which gives you the rb.drag = 0. You're never changing the `rb.drag` after setting it once.

Comment: Thank you @Maakep. I assumed that adding force to the rigid body would insure its velocity was set to a new value in a new direction, and that the magnitude value would follow also.

Comment: I haven't tested it but I'm assuming it is so, the physics is not calculated in Update(). Update is run every frame so I'm guessing that it, at some frame, isn't moving above 1 magnitude which sets drag to 0 for all future. You can easily check this by setting a Debug.Log(rb.velocity.magnitude); in the Update method. I'd love to hear the results

Comment: One way to fix this would probably be to just do: `else if (rb.drag != yourMagnitude) { rb.drag = yourMagnitude; }` on that if. So that it floats on low speeds and is reduced on high speeds.

Answer (score 2):

As @Maakep said, the problem comes from the fact you set the **Rigidbody** velocity to `0` and check if this velocity is `<= 1` right afterward (the force is only applied later).

To solve your problem you could do something like this:

```
public bool applyNextFrame = false;

protected override void Update()
{
    if(applyNextFrame && rb.velocity.magnitude <= 1)
    {
        rb.drag = 0;
        applyNextFrame = false;
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        Vector3 dir = Random.onUnitSphere;
        rb.AddForce(dir * 10, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        applyNextFrame = true;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this solution is far from flawless since you can have a problem if your **Rigidbody** configuration (mass, drag and force applied) applies different velocity values: therefore, you won't be able to fully control when the drag will reach `0` (this may be completely intentional depending on your project !) :)

You can look to the execution order diagram located in [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) for further information: you can see the *Internal physics update* happens before the *Update()* (when you call `rb.AddForce(...)` it's actually only applied during the next *Internal physics update*).

Also note I changed `Input.GetKeyDown("space")` to `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)`: this avoids typo problems if you mistype `space`.

*Hope this helps,*